# Error : 6 Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 4709 23 form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-3.0

```
    // <param name="sender">The sender of the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event args</param>
    private async void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseMovement == true) //if we can registre mouse events
        {

            Rectangle scr = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea; //Get the screen size
            if (!IsRdFull) //If not full screen mode
            {
                scr = pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle; //Get the picturebox's size
            }
            try
            {
                int mx = (e.X * resx) / scr.Width; //Calculate remote MouseX coordinate
                int my = (e.Y * resy) / scr.Height; //Calculate remote MouseY coordinate

                if (rmouse == 1) //If we are allowed to move the mouse
                {
                    if (plx != e.X || ply != e.Y) //Compare with the previous values and if mouse moved then
                    {
                        rMoveCommands.Add("rmove-" + mx + ":" + my); //Add mouse movement to the command list
                        plx = e.X; //Set the last X position to the current one
                        ply = e.Y; //Set the last Y position to the current one

                        mouseMovement = false; //Disable movement logging
                    }
                    //Wait for 200 ms
                    await Task.Delay(200); //this should stop the spammings of send commands -move the coursor very slowly and it will lockup so i added this
                    //Re enable mouse movement
                    mouseMovement = true; //and this switch ,cant send again for 200 ms - it works perfectly i am happy with it :-)
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("mouse move rd error ERROR = " + ex.Message); //Debug Function
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not written as a question. Try to see if the `{` and the `}` match correctly. Try to cut less relevant parts of the code away to obtain a minimal example that still has the problem. Then you will likely solve the problem yourself in the process. If not, post the minimal reproducing code here, instead.

Comment: thanks for your help